# Detect ios wkwebview resource load failure

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a url which loads an html file, which in turn loads one more resource (a javascript file) via its script tag.
I am loading this url in WKWebView on iOS.

If internet is good, then `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` is called after html and javascript file both are downloaded. Then i show a popup to user that url loaded successfully.

If internet gets interrupted before javascript file gets downloaded completely, then also `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` is called immediately. Now how should i detect that url hasn't loaded completely, so that i can show to user in a popup that he is having bad internet.

I tried to use `didFailProvisionalNavigation` and `didFail navigation` , but they don't get called, rather `didFinish navigation` is called.